# Reading float using scanf in c

Tags: c, printf, string-formatting, scanf

i have a structure which contains a float variable,

```
struct MyStruct{
    float p;
}newMyStruct;
```

And i am reading a value into it using `scanf`

```
int main(){
    scanf("%f",&(newMyStruct.p));
}
```

The problem is when i print it using `printf("%f",newMyStruct.p)` it prints '0.000000'. Also i get a warning that says the arugment is double while the format expects it to be float(warning for the `scanf("%f",&(newMyStruct.p));` statement).When i change `scanf()` syntax to
`scanf("%0f",&(newMyStruct.p));`,`printf("%0f",newMyStruct.p);` prints the float value correctly but the compiler gives another warning(something related to precision being 0).
Also `printf("%2f",newMyStruct.p)` prints the float number in some other format.

So, my question is how do i get rid of all these warnings and read a proper float variable which can be properly printed as well.

I dont have access to the laptop i generally code on and hence i cannot provide proper warnings.

Comment: its a typo in the question...i do use `&`

Comment: The `scanf()` warning is unlikely "format expects it to be float".  More likely is "format expects it to be float *".  Please provide what you enter and what prints out.

Comment: Probably you scanned a 32-bit float into the bottom of a `double` that was already `0.0`, so you just created a tiny subnormal value (only the mantissa non-zero), so printing it with `%f` (not scientific notation) rounds it to zero.  Your [mcve] uses `float` but that's very likely not what you actually ran.

Answer (score 5):

Edit:

I can't reproduce the problem. Everything works as expected when I use the following code compiled with gcc:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct MyStruct {
  float p;
} newMyStruct;

int main() {
  scanf("%f", &(newMyStruct.p));
  printf("%f\n", newMyStruct.p);
}
```

The output of gcc --version is as follows:

> gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
scanf("\n%f",&(newMyStruct.p));
```

The below code might read an empty value automatically.

```
scanf("%f",&(newMyStruct.p));
```