# Polynomial multiplication (ax+b)*(cx+d). Strange output when any co-efficient is floating number

Tags: c

Please see the code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a, b, c, d;
int p2, p1, p0;

printf("Enter a:");
scanf("%d",&a);
printf("Enter b:");
scanf("%d",&b);
printf("Enter c:");
scanf("%d",&c);
printf("Enter d:");
scanf("%d",&d);

p2 = a*c;
p1 = a*d + b*c;
p0 = b*d;
printf("The product is: %dx^2+%dx+%d\n",p2,p1,p0);
return 0;
}
```

Output is as follows:

```
Enter a:1.5

Enter b:Enter c:Enter d:The product is 3x^2+0x+0
```

Can anyone explain this? Once we give 1.5, it is not accepting the values for remaining co-efficients. How did we get that output?

Comment: you are trying to read float value to int.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading float using scanf in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254584/reading-float-using-scanf-in-c)

Comment: Please try to be precise with your question. There is no floating number involved in your multiplication. All operands are `int`.

Comment: Hi Gerhardh,  why scanf function is not allowing me to enter the remaining input values , If I give 1.5 as input to first variable. That's is my issue here. Please see StoryTeller answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost: the `1.5` in the standard input is not a a floating point value. It's a string of characters which *may be interpreted* as floating point value. It's also a string of characters that may not be interpreted *entirely* as an integer.

When scanning it, the `1` may be consumed to scan a value for `a`. But then the `.` is encountered, which may not be part of of a character sequence that stands for the value of an integer. So `scanf` will not consume it, it will stay in the input buffer until some other operation will deal with it.

But you call `scanf` again, and tell it to expect an integer. It still sees the `.`, which it can't handle. So it returns without consuming anything or writing anything into the argument you've given it. It reports the result of the operation in its return value, that you neglect to check. On the whole, your code doesn't take any error handling into account. It's written with the assumption `scanf` will always succeed, which is not realistic. You can read about [`scanf`'s return value here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Beyond that, you don't initialize any of your variables. That leaves them with indeterminate values. If `scanf` succeeds, those variables get assigned something else and your program runs successfully. But if `scanf` fails they don't, and you use those indeterminate values, resulting in your program having undefined behavior. There's no point trying to understand undefined behavior. You should fix your code instead. And you do that by handling failure properly. How you choose to handle `scanf`'s failure is up to you.

Answer (score 3):

**Declaration**

Declare all parameters as `double` instead of `int`. (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `p0`, `p1`, `p2`)

**Double format**

When using `%d`, an `int` is expected.

Use `%lf` when working with doubles.

This refers both to `scanf` and `printf`.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    double a, b, c, d;
    double p2, p1, p0;

    printf("Enter a:");
    scanf("%lf",&a);
    printf("Enter b:");
    scanf("%lf",&b);
    printf("Enter c:");
    scanf("%lf",&c);
    printf("Enter d:");
    scanf("%lf",&d);

    p2 = a*c;
    p1 = a*d + b*c;
    p0 = b*d;
    printf("The product is: %lfx^2+%lfx+%lf\n",p2,p1,p0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why scanf function is not allowing me to enter the remaining input values , If I give 1.5 as input to first variable. That's is my issue here. Please see StoryTeller answer